# pinax0.9a2 does not work with wsgi and apache

Tags: mod-wsgi, pinax

I am trying to deploy pinax0.9a2 with Apache 2.22 and WSGI 3.3. I am using the wsgi.py provided by pinax. But I got the 500 error and the following error in the apache error log:

```
[Sun Aug 19 03:31:55.895469 2012] [core:error] [pid 9045:tid 140546171721472] [client 107.192.29.14:62182] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

[Sun Aug 19 03:31:56.424077 2012] [core:notice] [pid 7789:tid 140546404792064] AH00052: child pid 9225 exit signal Aborted (6)

[Sun Aug 19 03:31:56.742536 2012] [core:error] [pid 9044:tid 140546196899584] [client 107.192.29.14:62183] Invalid status line from script 'wsgi.py': Status
ng.co: Objects/stringobject.c:115: PyString_FromString: Assertion `str != ((void *)0)' failed.

[Sun Aug 19 03:31:56.966168 2012] [core:error] [pid 9044:tid 140546196899584] [client 107.192.29.14:62183] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

[Sun Aug 19 03:31:57.426321 2012] [core:notice] [pid 7789:tid 140546404792064] AH00052: child pid 9243 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Apache httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/mysite

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/usr/local/apache2/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/apache2/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/mysite">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

import pinax.env


# setup the environment for Django and Pinax
pinax.env.setup_environ(__file__)


# set application for WSGI processing
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, its because your sys.path doesn't include pinax.  Most of my wsgi scripts start by setting the system path so that pinax and django are findable by the python that is running in mod_wsgi.

```
import sys
sys.path = [
"/home/username/Python/project/project/apps",
"/home/username/Python/project/project",
"/home/username/Python/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/django-mailer",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/django-axes",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/django-notification",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/pinax",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/django-email-confirmation",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/idios",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/pil-withg4-dev/PIL",
"/home/username/Python/project/src/django-deployment",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7/lib-tk",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7/lib-old",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload",
"/usr/lib/python2.7",
"/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2",
"/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk",
"/home/username/Python/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages",
"/home/username/Python/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL",
"/home/username/Python/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.8.0.13",
"/home/username/Python/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL",
]
```

Put these lines like these at the TOP of your wsgi file.